# How To Form Complex Where Filters In Loopback Using REST Style Syntax

Tags: rest, conditional-statements, loopbackjs

For consistency we need to use the REST URL style syntax (rather than JSON style syntax) when calling our Loopback apis. However, we are having difficulty structuring complex 'where' filters that include both 'and' and 'or' operators. There does not appear to be a way to group mixed conditional logic. For example, how would we create the equivalent of this SQL statement using REST syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE (type='retail' OR type='nonprofit') AND terms='monthly'
```

For example, this does not work:

```
/api/customer?filter[where][or][0][type]=retail&filter[where][or][1][type]=nonprofit&filter[where][and][2][terms]=monthly
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? Having trouble with the same thing. Guessing it has to be the [stringified JSON syntax](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Querying-data.html#using-stringified-json-in-rest-queries)? The [docs](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html#and--or) just ignore the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
   /api/customer?filter={
   "where": {
       "or": [ 
           {"type":"retail"}, 
           {"type":"nonprofit"},
           "and": [{"terms":"monthly}]
           ]
       } 
   }
```

Take a look to [Where filter](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html) in "More complex example"

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to work out a similar issue. Looks like you are pretty close, but I believe `and` is actually the top level comparison, and you are writing your query as if `or` is. So maybe..

```
/api/customer?filter[where][and][0][or][0][type]=retail&filter[where][and][0][or][1][type]=nonprofit&filter[where][and][1][terms]=monthly
```

I have no way to confirm this though as I do not have a functioning local environment with which to test it. Let us know if it works out. Thanks!

Update: Looks like this question has already been answered. https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3017 BLUF, it isn't possible in Loopback. Use the stringified JSON option.